# Picklist API name in Formulas

Tags: picklist, spring17

In Spring '17 I am trying to use picklist value API name in a formula.
How can I access a picklist value API name in a formula like ISPICKVAL?

Comment: You can find the name of any field the same way. Look at the object configuration in the `Setup` menu, or use describes. Is it a standard or custom object? Also why not just use the formula builder functionality that injects the field for you?

Comment: Are you referencing [this feature](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/keeping-picklist-integrations-safe-using-api-names.html)? - I don't think it's documented somewhere, or even possible as of now. You better to ask this in [Global, Restricted Custom Picklists group](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009PDtCAM)

Comment: Moving this to an answer instead

Comment: @Oleksiy, Yes I am referring to this feature. I want to refer to the picklist value API name in a Workflow formula, instead of referring to the label like I used to do before spring '17

Comment: See below. There is no such thing as referring to the label in a formula. It'll always be the API name.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Formula fields already see the API name **and only the API name** (yes, even `TEXT(fieldName)` gets you the API name, not the label). There is currently no way to fetch the label instead from a formula field. On the plus side, this means that existing formulas will not break if you re-label the picklist values in the future, as long as you keep the API name fixed.

In general - picklist values in unilingual Salesforce orgs are now behaving similarly to how they behave in Translation Workbench for multilingual orgs. The **API name**  is the authoritative value of each picklist option. It's what you see by default when you obtain it in code, and it's what you must set it to when assigning a value. **The label is now a translation** that is only used in display contexts.

In SOQL, querying a picklist gets you the API name. Querying using `toLabel(field name)` gets you the translation.

In Visualforce, two things that used to be the same for unilingual orgs no longer are (but these have been different in multilingual orgs all along):

`{!Contact.LeadSource}` <-- this will display the API name.

`<apex:outputField value="{!Contact.LeadSource}" />` <-- this will display the translation

Comment: Minor typo in explanation. <apex:outputField> will display translation - <apex:outputText> (as originally written) will not.