# When renaming Picklist Value Labels, where else should I be making changes?

Tags: apex, api, formula-field, picklist, validation-rule

We are renaming some picklist vaules that are heavily referenced in formulas, validation rules, and Apex/VF code. My understanding is that any references in formulas or code are looking at the API name and not the label - which allows us to not have to change the name throughout our existing code. However, this is assuming that none of our code is explicitly referencing the labels of the picklist values - most of our code references picklists types with '' which I now assume is the API in this case, but I could be wrong (ex. Type = 'Amazing').

Also, if our existing test classes are using the API name as an input, but really should be the new label - does that need to change to the proper text input of the new name?

[Picklist API name in Formulas](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160356/picklist-api-name-in-formulas)
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/keeping-picklist-integrations-safe-using-api-names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API name is used everywhere. It is really unlikely you're relying on a label, especially since those are also translated depending on the language of the user. You should not be using or depending on picklist labels anywhere in your code, and if you are, you should fix that. If you change the API name, then you'd need to check your code for any references to the API name, though.

Comment: So in this example of Object.Type__c == 'Amazing'... the word Amazing is considered to be the API name and not the Label?

Comment: @JustinGuay That's correct. The database saves the API values, so anywhere you use the raw field value it's the API name, not the label.

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much!